# Slots in optical incremental encoder

Tags: sensor

How can I calculate the amount of slots I need in my optical incremental encoder   's code wheel? For example, how many slots there should be, if I want to determine the position of screw which is connected to motor (pitch = 8mm and resolution 2mm).

Comment: Sounds like you need to be able to resolve to the nearest quarter of a revolution. 8mm per revolution divided by 2mm per count gives four counts per revolution. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many different values do you want to encode? With 1 slot you can encode two values. 2 slots give 4 values,  3 slots give 8, etc.